# Is there anything I can read about the Buddhist tradition today?

Tags: reference-request, modern-world

I've read the book *Makers of Modern Korean Buddhism*, and it was really interesting to read about the recent history of Buddhism, in Korea. And there's quite a few books on how Buddhism came to America etc.. And I have a few biographies of important monks. And I've read a bit about Bodhidharma, ch'an history in China, Tibetan dissemination, and the like.

But is there any other scholarship, like the book on Korea above, I can read about recent Buddhist history, rather than personalities, today?

Answer (score 1):

*The Broken Buddha* isn't exactly a history -- more of a snapshot, a description, an account of the author's personal experiences -- his description of people he met and their attitudes and behaviours which he saw ... not about "personalities", in that the people he describes are unnamed or not famous.

*Seven Years in Tibet* is history (ending in 1950) -- but by a non-Buddhist, and more about the culture, society, geography and politics of Tibet at the time, than about Buddhism.

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful. Not sure if this is the direction you were seeking or if it's too general.

http://www.sangharakshita.org/pdfs/a_buddhist_manifesto.pdf